# Chrome refuses to declare variable in injected script

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I have a Greasemonkey script which injects javascript into the page which is supposed to add a hyperlink which calls a variable when clicked. The variable is a function that hides the link and shows a player. However, when I click the link, the page error log says that playaudio is not defined. Here is my code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          AudioPlayer
// @include       http://mysite.com/*
// ==/UserScript==
function exec(fn) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute("type", "application/javascript");
    script.textContent = '(' + fn.toString() + ')();';
    document.body.appendChild(script); // run the script
    //document.body.removeChild(script); // clean up
}
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    exec(function () {
        jQuery(".field-name-field-mp3link").append('<audio controls="" autoplay="" style="margin-left:10px; display:none;" src=""></audio>');
        var playaudio = (function () {
            jQuery('.field-name-field-mp3link > audio').attr('src', jQuery('.field-name-field-mp3link > .field-items > .field-item > a').attr('href'));
            jQuery('.field-name-field-mp3link > audio').css('display', 'block');
            jQuery('.field-name-field-mp3link > a').css('display', 'none');
        });
        jQuery(".field-name-field-mp3link").append('<a href="javascript:playaudio();" style="margin-right:5px;">Listen</a>');
    });
}, false);
```

I should add that it works perfectly when I use chrome's builtin Javascript console to run the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it, you are declaring `playaudio` local to the function, and so clicking on a hyperlink `javascript:playaudio();` wouldn't work since `playaudio` is not in the global scope.

```
var playaudio = (function(){...});
jQuery(".field-name-field-mp3link").append('<span style="margin-right:5px;">Listen</span>');    
jQuery(".field-name-field-mp3link > span").click(playaudio);
```

**EDIT:** By keeping playaudio in the local scope as above and calling it via a click-handler on injected element, you can avoid polluting the global scope of the document, especially, say, if the document already had a "playaudio" method on window before your script was injected...

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I kept it an anchor so it would still be a regular link, but I changed the href to "javascript:;". I also noticed that I had the margin set wrong. I thought you had it mixed up in your example, but then I checked and sure enough, it was margin-right (it was supposed to be margin-left)! Thanks

Comment: If I understand right, the jQuery.click simply passes the code in playaudio to the click handler, correct?

Comment: Yup. `click`, and any other events, take an actual Function to execute. You could directly pass a function through, like: `.click(function(e){...})`. Though, there are several benefits with declaring the function first; one of which is if you ever wanted to call the **same** `playaudio` function on a different event, or at a different time.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your `playaudio` variable is bound to the context of anonymous function run by `exec`.

The `javascript:playaudio();` href is a call to `playaudio` in the global context, i. e. to `window.playaudio` which is indeed left undefined.

Try to replace `var playaudio` with `window.playaudio`.

Comment: Does this expose GreaseMonkey to the page JS like unsafeWindow (which doesn't exist in chrome)?